# Puppetter Problems, waitForNavigation() returns immediately

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I downloaded the latest version of Puppeteer a couple weeks ago, so I'm new with it. The first thing I noticed is that

```
await this.page.waitForNavigation();
```

does not seem to work. If I run in not headless mode and debug, I can see the waitForNavigation() returns as soon as navigation **starts**, not **finishes**. Who cares when navigation starts? You can't do anything until navigation is complete.

How can I be sure a page is ready? Right now I have had to fill my code with lots of

```
await this.page.waitFor(SomeDelayMs);
```

Comment: Can you provide small test scripts where these functions do not work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you're better off using:
`await page.waitForSelector('your_selector')`
That will cause puppeteer to wait until a specific selector is available before continuing execution. 
You can also use something like this if you're dealing with something that only shows up once clicked:
`await page.waitForSelector('your_selector', {visible: True})`